# RMI y como registrar objetos en un Registry remoto (error)

Tags: java

Tengo el siguiente código:

La interfaz *MasterServices* (que usará cualquier objeto remoto que se quiera registrar):

```
    package registro;

    /**
     *
     * @author eb76
     */

    import java.rmi.Remote;
    import java.rmi.RemoteException;

    /**
     * Define que pueden hacer los nodos Master.
     */
    public interface MasterServices extends Remote {

        public void registerSlave(SlaveServices slave) throws RemoteException;
    }
```

El objeto Master (que implementará la interfaz MasterServices):

```
package registro;

/**
 *
 * @author eb76
 */
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;

public class Master extends UnicastRemoteObject implements MasterServices {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    static final String RMI_NAME = "Master";

    private final Registry registry;

    protected Master(Registry registry) throws RemoteException {
        super();
        this.registry = registry;
    }

        @Override
    public void registerSlave(SlaveServices slave) throws RemoteException {
        String rmiName;
        try {
            rmiName = slave.getRmiName();

            registry.rebind(rmiName, slave);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        }
        System.out.println("Registered: " + rmiName);
    }   
}
```

La *main class MasterMain* (pone en funcionamiento el registro):

```
package registro;

/**
 *
 * @author eb76
 */
import java.rmi.Naming;
import java.rmi.RMISecurityManager;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;

public class MasterMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Registry registro;

                try {
                    registro = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(Registry.REGISTRY_PORT);
                }
                catch (RemoteException e) { 
                    registro = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(Registry.REGISTRY_PORT);
                }

        Master master = new Master(registro);

        registro.rebind(Master.RMI_NAME, master);
        System.out.println("Waiting for someone wake me up. " + Master.RMI_NAME);
        MasterMain masterMain = new MasterMain();
        synchronized (masterMain) {
            try {
                masterMain.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("Me han despertado, tengo que terminar la ejecución.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Al ejecutar este último archivo, me tira esta excepción:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 192.168.65.1; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:619)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(UnicastRef.java:342)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.rebind(Unknown Source)
    at registro.MasterMain.main(MasterMain.java:37)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:40)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:148)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:613)
    ... 5 more
```

En esta línea de *MasterMain*:

```
registro.rebind(Master.RMI_NAME, master);
```

¿Qué es lo que falla?

Comment: Pareciera que es un problema más de tu firewall que no abre los puertos, si estas en linux intenta con telnet 192.168.65.1 1099 (puerto default de RMI)